# Connection Time Out JDBC-MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, connection

I have a Java application running Win 7 connecting to MySQL on the same host.   Eclipse IDE shows the following error every time after 8-10mins.

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1070)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2214)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:781)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:348)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at iProclassHandlers.IProclass_Info_DAO.conn2SQL(IProclass_Info_DAO.java:151)
    at iProclassHandlers.IProclass_Info_DAO.toString(IProclass_Info_DAO.java:140)
    at iProclassParsers.IProclass_Info_Parser.printData(IProclass_Info_Parser.java:67)
    at iProclassParsers.IProclass_Info_Parser.runParser(IProclass_Info_Parser.java:38)
    at iProclassParsers.IProclass_main.main(IProclass_main.java:19)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: Is your mysql up and running ?Seems like its down.

Comment: yup....my mysql server is up n running...i guess its d problem with jdbc or may b with mysql jar file....

Comment: It is not clear to me if the exception is thrown at the first connection after an 8-10min timeout or if the application works correctly for 8-10min and then fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't make JDBC connection to MySQL (using Java, IntelliJ, and Linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102912/cant-make-jdbc-connection-to-mysql-using-java-intellij-and-linux)

Comment: my aplication works very fine for 8-10 mins and fails then....

Answer (score 0):

This reported MySQL [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47494) might explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

[Tomcat6 can't connect to MySql (The driver has not received any packets from the server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172570/tomcat6-cant-connect-to-mysql-the-driver-has-not-received-any-packets-from-the)

https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally

[Can't make JDBC connection to MySQL (using Java, IntelliJ, and Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102912/cant-make-jdbc-connection-to-mysql-using-java-intellij-and-linux)